# Using git worktree add in Jenkinsfile gives invalid reference error

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, git-worktree

First poster here.
I started working with jenkins a couple months ago and I run into a problem where I cant figure out whats causing the issue.
Is it not seeing the master branch that should be added? the path seems fine, it works locally. Attached a picture below:

This is my jenkinsfile:

```
   stage('Build image') {
    sh('git worktree add ./all/src_master master')
```

this is the output:

```
[Pipeline] { (Build image)
[Pipeline] sh
    + git worktree add ./all/src_master master
    fatal: invalid reference: master
[Pipeline] }
```

rev parse gives this:

```
[Pipeline] { (Build image)
[Pipeline] sh
+ git rev-parse master
fatal: ambiguous argument 'master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
master
[Pipeline] }
```

[git worktree add reference error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SLbY.png)

Update:
What solved my problem:

```
    git config remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    git fetch --all
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! First, paste text into the question, please. If you don't know how to format it, no worries, one editor will probably do it (even I could do it) and then you can see how it's done. Then, what is the output of `git rev-parse master` (add that to the question too)?

Comment: See @eftshift0's comments and also [ask]. Meanwhile, the problem is likely one or both of two things: the branch might be named `main` instead of `master`, and your Jenkins setup might be using a *shallow and/or single-branch* clone so that it does not have `master` available. The second of these is a Jenkins setup item. The first of these is a Git item.

Comment: @torek Thanks for the reply. There is definitely a master branch, we still use master instead of main. Trying to figure out how could I make the branches available, I'm not using any clone command either.

Comment: @eftshift0 I added git rev-parse master.

Comment: I'm no Jenkins guru but I have had to deal with Jenkins in the past. It tends to make shallow, single-branch clones for speed; there's always a way to disable this, or you can sometimes (depending on Jenkins setup) run `git fetch --unshallow` and the like in the Jenkinsfile scripts. But mostly I hate Jenkins because it's opaque and very not-Unix-like and the documentation is awful.

Comment: @torek 
`+ git fetch --unshallow`
`fatal: --unshallow on a complete repository does not make sense`

Comment: You do not have a master branch in your local repo (that's what the output of rev-parse tells you).

Comment: @eftshift0 yes, I'm trying now to be able to pull and checkout a branch. But even having issues with that aswell.

Comment: OK, that means you don't have a shallow repo. Maybe you have a single-branch one: check / fix the `remote.origin.fetch` setting, in that case.